# How to communicate with GSM modem from c++ code

Tags: c++, sms, usb, communication

I have huawei GSM modem and I wish to read and send SMS from my c++ application. Does anybody know how to establish communication from code (what are communication protocols, I know how to connect to serial port and read and write data there).

I have read something about AT commands but don't know how to apply it.

Comment: You should read the documentation for the modem, it should list all commands needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just sent the AT commands as strings via the serial port

Comment: It works when I do it in Windows using visual studio and C#, but I can't get it to work under linux using Qt.

Comment: Just a thought: are you sending the right newline character value at the end of the command string?