# How to manage the received SMS's in a gsm modem connected to a pc?

Tags: c++, usb, gsm, at-command, modem

i am working on a project that a computer should manage the data receiving as sms text in standard predefined coding from multiple senders. the senders are some embedded sytems that send error situations of a machine via sms messages.
i am an electronic engineer not  software and i made the senders circuits those send the information (errors) to a central monitoring site.
therefore in the site should be a gsm modem connected to a pc which receives the messages and the pc should have a software to be able to read the messages from gsm modem and sort them and log them and give the operator some reports based on for example which kind of errors has been occurred more and etc.
my question is about developing this software to be able to read data from usb port and then manage them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will hardly define by the specification of your GSM modem.
Maybe this OP will help you : 
[How to communicate with GSM modem from c++ code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22662436/how-to-communicate-with-gsm-modem-from-c-code)

Many GSM modem use the AT command, see also GSM section on this page : 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hayes_command_set#GSM
and this : 
[output of AT command c++ code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16663848/output-of-at-command-c-code)

and look at the at-command tag also